# Queue Manager User ID initialization failed

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

I am trying to connect to MQ using IBM.XMS and  getting below error in event viewer. Any thoughts?

```
9/30/2015 01:57:51 - Process(5272.66) User(mquser) Program(amqrmppa.exe) Host(MTADEV2) Installation(Installation1) VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(CRMDQM1)
Queue Manager User ID initialization failed.  
The call to initialize the User ID failed with CompCode 2 and Reason 2063.  
Correct the error and try again.
and then
9/30/2015 01:57:51 - Process(5272.66) User(mquser) Program(amqrmppa.exe) Host(MTADEV2) Installation(Installation1) VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(CRMDQM1)
Channel 'DRM.ADMIN.SVRCONN' to host 'MTADEV2 (10.0.0.11)' ended abnormally.  
The channel program running under process ID 5272(15236) for channel 'DRM.ADMIN.SVRCONN' ended abnormally. The host name is 'MTADEV2 (10.0.0.11)'; in some cases the host name cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'.  
Look at previous error messages for the channel program in the error logs to determine the cause of the failure. Note that this message can be excluded completely or suppressed by tuning the "ExcludeMessage" or "SuppressMessage" attributes  under the "QMErrorLog" stanza in qm.ini. Further information can be found in the System Administration Guide.
```

Comment: Where is the MTADEV2 user defined?  Is it local or AD Domain user?  2063 is MQRC_SECURITY_ERROR.  Basically, MQ Is not able to connect to underlying user management platform to validate the user.  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q041320_.htm

Comment: Do you have AMS on the system?

Comment: @Deeps - Could you please let me know the solution for this issue? I'm getting the same error and unable to proceed further. Appreciate any help or insight you could provide on this issue. If you could share your sample Dockefile and code that would be great or provide details to resolve.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @testbgtestbg you are actually getting a 2035 not a 2063.  The OP of this post was using the XMS.NET API to connect to a windows queue manager,  you are using pymqi to connect to a docker Linux queue manager.   This issue is likely unrelated to your issue.

Comment: @JoshMC - Thanks! It seemed to be a similar issue and so posted. Thanks for letting me know.